# Screen Dimension/Resolution setup for windows application in Karate Robot Framework.Button's or menu items are not getting located at exact location

Tags: robotframework, karate

im using Karate Robot Framework automation on a Virtual machine where the dimension/resolution of screen seems different .So when i to  locate a button or menuitem on my application it detects the button or menuitem but the highlight(Red border ) goes a bit out of the actual button which makes the click() click  away from the actual button.

Is there any way i can fix the resolution setup for the robot.

i have tried to use a bigger display than my laptop and extended the display .For some screen's it works for some it doesn't

Comment: this is something that can be improved: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1775 - if you can contribute code or influence your team to do so - that would be ideal